# what do the brackets mean? $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{n}^{3/2}[\sqrt {{n}^{3}+3}-\sqrt {{n}^{3} -3}] $

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

**Calculate: $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{n}^{3/2}[\sqrt {{n}^{3}+3}-\sqrt {{n}^{3}
-3}]$**

---

What do the brackets mean? I know sometimes they are used to denote a function that returns only the integer part of a number, like $f(x) = [x]$  has values of $0$ on $(0,1)$ and then jumps to $1$ on [1,2) and then $2$ on $[2,3)$ and so on...
Is this what is meant here?

Comment: If the square brackets meant integer part, as you speculate, the answer would be fairly easily $0$. I am reasonably confident that you are expected to think of them as a variant of ordinary parentheses. If you want, you can cover all possible bases by adding a remark about what happens if one interprets the square brackets as meaning integer part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the brackets are equivalent to $($ $)$. I am saying so because we don't *usually* use the integer part function in a calculus or analysis context. If you are in a number theory context, then those might mean the integer part function, but then I don't see why you would be computing this limit.

Hope that helps,

Comment: We don't use integer part in calculus or analysis context? Really?

Comment: Limits are sometimes important in number theory, too.

Comment: I looked at the question as an exercise in a course. Don't you agree now?

Comment: thanks, I was getting no where with integer-part. To all you professors and teachers out there, remember that a small typo or brackets instead of regular parentheses can mean hours of confusion for your students. (I took this from a previous test so maybe the professor was there to explain that these are just ordinary parenthesis and were miss-typed for some reason)

Comment: Patrick: I do agree that it is equivalent to $()$ in this context.  I don't agree that we don't use integer part in calculus or analysis context.  I have personally assigned limit problems that involve the floor function, and they show up on this site sometimes too (many of them likely exercises in courses).  @nofe: Thank you for the advice.  I prefer $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to $[x]$ anyway for the floor function.

Comment: @Jonas : I added the "*usually*" so that my point is more clear.

Comment: I really do not see the problem...
$\lfloor x \rfloor$ means the floor function (rounded down)$\\$ 
$\lceil x \rceil$ means the ceiling function (rounded up) $\\$
$\{x\}$ means the fractional part of x. \\ In almost all cases [] are normal bracets, used to make the math more readable. Eg using 5 nested () normal parenthesis would often look bad. A bit of thinking is also adviced when reading mathematics =) Cheers

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar : There's no "problem", there's just a question. =P

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely to be integer part, as that would make the $n^{3/2}$ term irrelevant.

I am quite sure that it is the normal brackets: ().

Answer (score 0):

Or, using the binomial theorem,
${n}^{3/2}(\sqrt {{n}^{3}+3}-\sqrt {{n}^{3}-3})
= n^3(\sqrt {1+3/n^3}-\sqrt {1-3/n^3})
$
$
= n^3((1 + 3/(2n^3) + O(1/n^6))
- (1 - 3/(2n^3) + O(1/n^6))
$
$
n^3(3/n^3 + O(1/n^6)
= 3 + O(1/n^3)
$.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket function is denoted by [ ], and is defined as [x] is equal to the largest integer that is equal or less then x
For Example 
   (1)  [5.5]=5
   (2)  [-0.1]=-1
   (3)  [-1.9]=-2

Answer (score 0):

The bracket function $[x]$ means the greatest value of $x$. For example: If we put $x = 5.5$ then the value returned by this function will be $x = 5$. Let's see $[5.5] = 5$ because the greatest integer is $5$.